# how to use middleware in rails to get current_user_id by JWT?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, jwt

I am new in Rails, I usually on Express using middleware to get user.id by decoded JWT,
it something like this

**/middleware/jwt.js**

```
const authentic = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header("token");
  if (!token) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "no token " });
  } else {
    try {
      const decoded = verifyJwt(token);
      const isAuth = await Person.findOne({ _id: decoded._id });
      if (!isAuth) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: `you are not authentic` });
      } else {
        // keys : _id, role, username
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }
};

export default authentic;
```

then I use it on routes, `app.use(authentic)`
so I can get `req.user.id` on each query I associated or populate

in rails, how to use middleware and required that authentic middle to get current_user_id ?? so I could associate it with other models, 
I am using the rails for API only, I would love to get some implementation for this without any gems like `devise` or others, just using JWT

here is on rails for JWT:

**/lib/json_web_token.rb**

```
class JsonWebToken
 class << self
   def encode(payload, exp = 24.hours.from_now)
     payload[:exp] = exp.to_i
     JWT.encode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
   end

   def decode(token)
     body = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)[0]
     HashWithIndifferentAccess.new body
   rescue
     nil
   end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided rails excerpt is only token (de-)coder, actual middleware looks very similar, it should be a callable object (either a proc/lambda, or more commonly an instance with `call` method):

```
class SomeMiddleware
  def initialize(app, params)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

```
# application.rb
config.middleware.use SomeMiddleware, some_optional: "params"
```

But for authentication you do not have to make that a middleware, for most cases a `before_action` in your `ApplicationController` can be sufficient.

Also you can look into using some gems like [knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock) or [devise-jwt](https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt)

Comment: i see about knock, but i dont know about device-jwt, which u use right now??

Comment: For api-only I'd go with `knock`